# EC2 user data script does not find commands

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to get a user data script working on EC2, Amazon Linux distro. The script does run, but for most commands, such as `ec2-metadata` or `gem` it complains about `command not found`. The tools are installed, and i can run them when I log in.

I guess, it has to do with the `PATH` not being set or something like that. How can I make the script behave as if I was running it in a shell?

Currently, I have started to work around with lines like the following, but it get's out of hand.
`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

Although not using Amazon Linux, I have managed to get my user script working without having to declare full paths by exporting PATH at the top of the file.

```
export=$PATH:/insert/your/path/here:/other/path/here
```